# Can we build linux kernel on a PC and install it on another PC?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I compiled a kernel on my computer and then I installed it in the same computer and it works fine. my question is how to install the same kernel on another computer?

Comment: If you're running a Debian derivative there are scripts that build proper `.deb` packages that you can copy to another PC and then install with the package manager. [Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_debian_etch) you can read instructions on how to do it. Other distributions have their own means to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: but but, [SO] is not the right place for this question. [SU] or [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com) are both more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy the `vmlinuz-[version number]` and `initrd.img-[version number]` files along with `/lib/modules/[version number]` to the other computer. And of course point the bootloader of the other machine to these files.

There are also tools that pack the kernel into *.deb packages which makes it easier to deploy. I think the program is called `make-kpkg` on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can even build kernels for different architectures

Comment: It's the same architecture and my question is how to do it and not is is possible to do it

Comment: There are lots of ways. You can make images, copy only the kernel .. it really depends of what you want to do so you will have to be much more precise in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to copy the zImage file over to the new computer. And modify GRUB or whatever bootloader you are using to load it.

For GRUB you can find the necessary information on how to do it [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html)

Comment: copying only the bzImage will not work, unless you do not use LKM at all. so you will have to copy the whole /lib/modules/`uname -r` subtree along with your bzImage.